# Copy char num[50] to std::string

Tags: c++, string

How to copy contents of char array to std::string (not conversion)

Ex :

```
void CApp::ChangeState(GameState* state)
{
std::string strImagePath;
// cleanup the current state
if ( !states.empty() ) {
    states.back()->Clean();
    states.pop_back();
    //states.back()->getImagePath( psImagepath );
}

// store and init the new state
states.push_back(state);
states.back()->Init();

//psImagepath = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
states.back()->getImagePath( psImagepath );

printf("MenuState Init path %s\n",psImagepath);

}
```

i want to copy my contents into strImagePath (consider strImage path is declared in class definition)

Comment: What is the char[] in this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the string's [constructor that takes a char array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
char arr[50];
//Fill your array, do stuff, etc, etc
<...>
std::string str(arr);
```

Note that the char array that you are passing to the constructor should be null-terminated.

Comment: This is, of course, assuming that the array contains a valid C-string. In case it doesn't, just add a second `size` parameter to the constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strImagePath.append(charArray)` to append the char[], or `strImagePath.assign(charArray)` to replace the previous content of `strImagePath` by the char[] content.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the constructor (`std::string(const char* str)`) or copy assignment operator (`std::string& operator=(const char* str)`).